# Oracle SQL merge does not insert when the destination table is empty

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to update/insert records in main schema from working schema using a merge statement. The piece of code that does the merge is as below.

```
MERGE INTO ods_workday.ORGANIZATION x
                USING (SELECT organization_id, organization_code, organization_type, organization_name, organization_description,  
                inactive, manager, leadership_role_assignee, organization_owner, supervisory_organization, 
                primary_site_reference, inactive_date, organization_subtype
                FROM ods_workday_w.ORGANIZATION) y
                ON (x.ORGANIZATION_ID = y.ORGANIZATION_ID)
                WHEN MATCHED THEN
                    UPDATE SET x.organization_code = y.organization_code, 
                                        x.organization_type = y.organization_type,
                                        x.organization_name = y.organization_name,
                                        x.organization_description = y.organization_description, 
                                        x.inactive = y.inactive,
                                        x.manager = y.manager, 
                                        x.leadership_role_assignee = y.leadership_role_assignee,
                                        x.organization_owner = y.organization_owner, 
                                        x.supervisory_organization = y.supervisory_organization,
                                        x.primary_site_reference = y.primary_site_reference,
                                        x.inactive_date = y.inactive_date, 
                                        x.organization_subtype = y.organization_subtype,
                                        x.UPDATE_TIME_STAMP = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                    WHERE x.organization_code <> y.organization_code OR
                                        x.organization_type <> y.organization_type OR
                                        x.organization_name <> y.organization_name  OR
                                        x.organization_description <> y.organization_description OR
                                        x.inactive <> y.inactive OR
                                        x.manager <> y.manager OR
                                        x.leadership_role_assignee <> y.leadership_role_assignee OR
                                        x.organization_owner <> y.organization_owner OR
                                        x.supervisory_organization <> y.supervisory_organization OR
                                        x.primary_site_reference <> y.primary_site_reference OR
                                        x.inactive_date <> y.inactive_date OR
                                        x.organization_subtype <> y.organization_subtype       
                WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                    INSERT(x.organization_id,  x.organization_code, x.organization_type, x.organization_name,
                    x.organization_description, x.inactive, x.manager, x.leadership_role_assignee,
                    x.organization_owner, x.supervisory_organization, x.primary_site_reference, x.inactive_date,
                    x.organization_subtype, x.UPDATE_TIME_STAMP)  
                    VALUES(y.organization_id,  y.organization_code, y.organization_type, y.organization_name,
                    y.organization_description, y.inactive, y.manager, y.leadership_role_assignee,
                    y.organization_owner, y.supervisory_organization, y.primary_site_reference, y.inactive_date,
                    y.organization_subtype, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

The code works fine when the destination table has records, but when the destination table is empty (has zero records than the merge).

Is there a way we can make the merge statement to work, when there are no records to start with in the target schema.

The Oracle database is 11g.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved.
I had not added a foreign key constraint present in source table because of which insert on zero records was not working.

Comment: good that you have sorted this out yourself; title says this is plsql, but this is sql